# Finding the slant asymptote of a radical function

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following function $f(x)=(x-2)^{1/3}(x+4)^{2/3}$. I'm asked to find all asymptotes of this function.

Clearly, there are no vertical asymptotes since there are no points of discontinuity. There are also no horizontal asymptotes since $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty}$

So that means I just need to check for the slant asymptotes.

I know that $\displaystyle m=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and $\displaystyle b=\lim_{x \to \infty}{(f(x)-mx)}$

$\displaystyle m=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$

$\displaystyle m=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(x-2)^{1/3}(x+4)^{2/3}}{x}$

$\displaystyle m=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x(1-\frac{2}{x})^{1/3}(1+\frac{4}{x})^{2/3}}{x}$

$\displaystyle m=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{1/3}\left(1+\frac{4}{x}\right)^{2/3}=1$

The problem is $b$.

$\displaystyle b=\lim_{x \to \infty}{(f(x)-mx)}$

$\displaystyle b=\lim_{x \to \infty}{((x-2)^{1/3}(x+4)^{2/3}-x)}$

The answer SHOULD be $2$ have no idea how to proceed however. I tried to manipulate this into L'hopital's rule but I don't think that's possible here... Can someone help out? Thanks!

Comment: Two possible ideas: • write the expression for $b$ as $\frac{f(x)}{1/x}$ and use l'Hôpital's rule; • use $a^{1/3}-b^{1/3} = \frac{a-b}{a^{2/3}+(ab)^{1/3}+b^{2/3}}$ with $a=(x-2)(x+4)^2$ and $b=x^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Another solution*

$$y=(x-2)^{1/3}(x+4)^{2/3}$$
$$y^3=(x-2)(x+4)^2=x^3+6 x^2-32=x^3\left(1+\frac{6}{x}-\frac{32}{x^2} \right)$$
$$y=x \sqrt[3]{1+\left(\frac{6}{x}-\frac{32}{x^2}\right)}$$

Now,to work  close to $0$,
$$x=\frac 1t \quad \implies \quad y=x \sqrt[3]{1+(6t-32t^2)}$$

Binomial expansion or Taylor series
$$\sqrt[3]{1+(6t-32t^2)}\sim 1+2 t-\frac{44 }{3}t^2$$
Back to $x$
$$y=x\left( 1+\frac{2}{x}-\frac{44}{3 x^2}   \right)=x+2-\frac{44}{3x}$$

So, the first and second terms give the equation of the slant asymptote.

The third term tells you, that the curve is above the asymptote if $x\to \infty$ and below the asymptote if $x\to -\infty$

With the third term, you can consider that is a curved asymptote.

Comment: If I was allowed to use the binomial series, I would 100% use this. That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 7):

Use [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem):
\begin{align}
(x-2)^{1/3}(x+4)^{2/3}&=x^{1/3}\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{1/3}
x^{2/3}\left(1+\frac{4}{x}\right)^{2/3} \\
&=x\left[1-\frac{2}{3x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right]
\left[1+\frac{8}{3x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right] \\
&=x\left[1+\frac{2}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right] \\
&=x+2+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right). \tag{1}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
b=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left((x-2)^{1/3}(x+4)^{2/3}-x\right)=2. \tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= (x-2)^{1/3}(x+4)^{2/3} \\
&= ((x-2)(x+4)^2)^{1/3} \\ 
&= (x^3+6x^2-32)^{1/3} \\ 
&= ((x^3+6x^2+12x+8)-(12x+40))^{1/3}
    & \textrm{complete the cube} \\ 
&= ((x+2)^3 - (12x+40))^{1/3} \\ 
&= (x+2)\left(1-\frac{12x+40}{(x+2)^3}\right)^{1/3}
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*} 
\frac{f(x)}{x+2} &= \left(1-\frac{12x+40}{(x+2)^3}\right)^{1/3} \rightarrow 1 \quad (x\to\infty).
\end{align*}